# Pyspark lag and lead function crashed after some use

Tags: pyspark

I have some issue when using Lag and Lead on pyspark.

I use this `dataActLag = dataAct.withColumn("infoDatetimeLag", lag(col("datetime")).over(Window.orderBy("datetime")))` code but after some execution it returns to me the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Could you help to understand why?
Thanks

Comment: it might be for some other piece of code. your code looks okay to be executed if you've imported things correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was actually some import issue. I fixed it by re-importing all lib. I don't understand why